# Navigate to specific TabBar item

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have a function that navigates me to whatever view I want:

```
func move(identifier: String , viewController : UIViewController)  {
        let mstoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: UIViewController = mstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
        viewController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

How can I convert it to navigate me to whatever tabBar item I want?
Or what can I use to navigate at whatever tabBar item I want?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this __viewController__ embedded in a __tabBar__?

Comment: @Adeel no i have two tabs and each of them has an add button which use this function to go to each view so they are not embedded in with my tabbar

Comment: Where exactly do you want to access this tabBar/tabItem?

Comment: At its first view

Comment: You aren't getting my point. Can you explain the scenario? Where is this tabBar and where do you you want to access it? In other words, where is this __first view__ w.r.t the tabBar?

Comment: @Adeel ok Lets say that i have a single view (outside of tab bar) and a button inside this view which when i tap it I want to navigate me to one of the two tabs I have (my tabbar has two tabs of a single view each)

Comment: Now I get it. If  that your tabBarController is the rootViewController of the app then you may access it from your __AppDelegate's__ window. Like this __window.roortViewController__.

Comment: @Adeel it is the root view controller but how can i specify which tab will be shown?

Comment: @Adeel I updated my question

Comment: try the solution below. I hope that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `UITabBarController` is your application's `rootViewController`, assuming that you know tab index you want to switch to this will do for you.

```
    let tabBarController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = tabIndex
    self.presentingViewController!.presentingViewController!.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
```

[image]

Comment: I added these lines inside my button's function (I changed tabIndex with 1) 
but nothing happend ( as rootViewcontroller you mean the initial viewcontroller right)

Comment: I added these lines to a button I have in the first tab and went me to the second tab but the button I have (second picture) its inside a viewcontroller outside the tabbar

Comment: It doesn't matter, your view controller can be anywhere. It needn't be in the tab bar controller. This is a generic solution.

Comment: That's strange because I posted the answer after verifying myself. However, do you see any warning/message in the console?

Comment: No nothing if i have only these two lines nothing happens when i tap the button if iuse the function to navigate back to tabbar it gets me the first item and not the second

Comment: @mikevorisis I have added a gif as a demonstration. Can you share your code where you show this `ViewController` that is outside of the `TabBarController` and where you are switching to the other tab?

Comment: Your code is working because your second viewcontroller(the one which has 2 buttons) is embeded in tabbar mine isn't. I used the function that i have in my question to navigate outside the tabbar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126455/discussion-between-adeel-and-mike-vorisis).

Answer (score 4):

In swift 4

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            self.selectedIndex = 3  //enter your tabbar no.
    }
```